# Docker build: meteor not found

Tags: docker, meteor

I am able to setup the meteor on my local machine. Has to push it to the EC2 container using the Docker Images. While doing the build step, the build process throwing the error meteor not found.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.3
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
COPY . /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN chmod -R 700 /usr/src/app/.meteor/local
RUN meteor run install 
RUN meteor build --server-only --directory build
```

Terminal Command:

> docker build -t meteor-test  .

Error Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What is the `/home/gitpod` directory in the third-to-last line?  Also note `RUN export ...` is a no-op; you need to use `ENV` to set environment variables.  I'd normally expect `docker build` to write text output; can you replace the screen shot with the text of the command you ran and its output?

Comment: I have modified the post, please check now

Answer (score 1):

meteor is not installing in your docker container because of certificate error while doing curl.

Fixed Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.3
RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ -k | sh
COPY . /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN chmod -R 700 /usr/src/app/.meteor/local
RUN meteor run install 
RUN meteor build --server-only --directory build
```

-k means insecure, which basically means it will not check the ssl certificate while doing curl.  If you feel the website is not trust worthy then don't do the curl with -k flag.